# Regex to find PHP ShortTag (<?)

Tags: regex, vim

I am currently updating some legacy PHP Code and in order to ease my job I would like to have a vim script that makes my life easier.
I have the following problem:
This old PHP Code has Opening tags such as
'<?' , '<?if' , '<?{' and '<?}'.

Obviously this is not best practice and with 7.3 it does not seem to work any more either.
Valid Opening Tags are '<?php' and '<?='

What I am currently trying to to is find all occurences of '<?' that do not start with '<?php' and '<?=' and replace these with '<?php'.

My current approach is ignoring at least the php ones with
`/<?[^p]`
Now I am wondering , why exactly `/<?[^p|^=] or  /<?[^p]|[^=]`  is not working + How I should go about replacing every occurrence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You can include `= and p` in the character class:

```
/<?[^p=]
```

Regarding how to replace, we need some examples.

But you can give this a try:

```
%s/<?[^p= ]\+/<?php/g
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To remove these `<?` not followed with `=` or `php`, use

```
%s/<?\(php\|=\)\@!//g
```

To replace `<?` not followed with `=` or `php` with `<?php` use

```
%s/<?\(php\|=\)\@!/&php/g
```

Here,

- `<?` - matches `<?` substring
- `\(php\|=\)\@!` - makes sure there is no `php` nor `=` immediately after the current location (a negative lookahead).

Note that `&` in the replacement pattern stands for the whole match value.